# Expected 1 input.ui-select-search but got '0' UI-Select

Tags: angularjs, ui-select, angular-ui-select

i am using  "ui-select": "^0.19.6".
As per my requirement i need to edit template "bootstrap/select-multiple.tpl.html" provided by ui-select. I am modifying using run

```
    var app = angular.module('demo', ['ngSanitize', 'ui.select']);
app.run(["$templateCache",function($templateCache){
  var tmpl = `<div class="ui-select-container ui-select-multiple ui-select-bootstrap dropdown
         form-control" ng-class="{open: $select.open}">
    <div ng-if="true">
        <div class="ui-select-match"></div>
        <input custom-directive enable-format="{{$ctrl.enableMobileNumberFilter}}" type="search" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off"
               spellcheck="false" class="ui-select-search input-xs"
               placeholder="{{$selectMultiple.getPlaceholder()}}" ng-disabled="$select.disabled"
               ng-click="$select.activate()" ng-model="$select.search" role="combobox" aria-expanded="{{$select.open}}"
               aria-label="{{$select.baseTitle}}" ng-class="{'spinner': $select.refreshing}" ondrop="return false;">
    </div>
    <div class="ui-select-choices"></div>
    <div class="ui-select-no-choice"></div>
</div>`
        $templateCache.put("bootstrap/select-multiple.tpl.html",tmpl);
    }])
```

I have just added ng-if ="true" (eventually this will replace with actual condition).
But it is throwing me an error "Expected 1 input.ui-select-search but got '0'"

It works just fine once we remove ng-if.

[Example plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bn2CRg5umm2GizWSS5vn?p=preview)

Comment: this might have something to do with the fact that `ng-if` creates new child scope..

Comment: is there any other way we can solve this issue